# Unshrinkable Div with percent height

Tags: html, css, height, percentage

In a project I am working on, I am trying to get the page's header height to be 5% of the screen. Obviously this is done with `height: 5%;`, however, I need the header to stay at 5% of the whole screen at ALL times. This means that if I were to shrink the browser window, the header div does NOT shrink proportionally as well. I need it to stay the same size, but the size needs to be set with the initial percentage. A website that I used for reference was github.com, as their header stays one size even when the browser window is shrunk. Flickr.com is another example of what I am looking for in a header. I have tried to use `min-height: XXpx;` (replacing the 'x' with numbers) but that was not effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript once the page has loaded to calculate the 5% of the window height & assign it to the header as its CSS height value. It will overwrite any set CSS values.

```
var h = window.innerHeight * 0.05;
getElementById('your-element-id').style.height = h+'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tryed vh(vertical height) calculation?

example

```
navbar{
min-height: 5vh;
max-height: xx;}
```